# How to create vcf file using java?

Tags: java, vcf-vcard

Could someone help me, please. How to create vcard file in java?
It must contain several strings
`String name
String family name
String phone
String email`

..and how to set types to these attributes such as `home`,`work`,etc? 
I haven't found anything useful over the internet, so I would like to turn to Stackoverflow community for some advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Java lib for this like https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard or you just create a vcard conform String and write it into a File. For information how a vcard looks like see the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a vcf file with pur java. I have found this by accident: [http://luckyjava.blogspot.de](http://luckyjava.blogspot.de/2013/02/how-to-create-vcard-in-java.html)

Because an url can going invalid, here the source code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Vcard
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  File f=new File("contact.vcf");
  FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(f);

  if(f.exists())
  {
   String str="BEGIN:VCARD\n" + 
     "VERSION:4.0\n" +
     "N:Gump;Forrest;;;\n" +
     "FN:Forrest Gump\n"+
     "ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.\n"+
     "TITLE:Shrimp Man\n"+
     "TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-111-555-1212\n"+
     "TEL;TYPE=home,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-404-555-1212\n"+
     "EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com\n"+
     "REV:20080424T195243Z\n"+
     "END:VCARD";
   fop.write(str.getBytes());
   //Now read the content of the vCard after writing data into it
   BufferedReader br = null;
   String sCurrentLine;
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("contact.vcf"));
   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
   {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
   }
   //close the output stream and buffer reader 
   fop.flush();
   fop.close();
   System.out.println("The data has been written");
  } else 
   System.out.println("This file does not exist");
 }
}
```