# Bad performance ML Kit barcode scanning

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I'm using Googles ML Kit for barcode scanning, and gathered the code below from the examples and tutorials provided by Google. However, the performance is dramatic; it takes several seconds, can be 10, 15 seconds, to recognize a barcode. Is there any way to improve this?

Also, how can this be used with inverted bar codes? I found that I need to invert the image, however, if in the Analyzer I try to get image.bitmapInternal or image.byteBuffer, it is always null.

Build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.0'
 // CameraX core library using camera2 implementation
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.2"
// CameraX Lifecycle Library
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.2"
// CameraX View class
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha31"
```

Then, in a fragment:

```
typealias BarCodeListener = (barCode: String) -> Unit
const val TAG = "ConnectorScanner"
[...]

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    startCamera()
}

private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
    val resolution = Size(720, 1280)
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        // Preview
        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(resolution)
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            }

        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(resolution)
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
            .build()

        val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, BarCodeAnalyzer { barCode ->
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Code: $barCode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    viewModel.onConnectorCodeScanned(barCode)
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                })
            }

        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        try {
            // Unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            // Bind use cases to camera
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer
            )

        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            showErrorDialog()
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
}
```

Image analyzer

```
private class BarCodeAnalyzer(private val listener: BarCodeListener) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(
            Barcode.FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX
        )
        .build()

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
        mediaImage?.let {
            val image =
                InputImage.fromMediaImage(it, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
                val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options)

            scanner.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                    if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                        barcodes.firstOrNull()?.rawValue?.let { barcode ->
                            Log.d(TAG, barcode)
                            listener(barcode)
                        }
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }
                }
        }
        imageProxy.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check out my QR code example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64504871/3437352. Barcode would be pretty similar too.

Answer (score 9):

With some luck, I found the solution to the performance issue, it's adding an OnCompleteListener and closing the images there. So the analyzer will be

```
scanner.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                    if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                        barcodes.firstOrNull()?.rawValue?.let { barcode ->
                            Log.d(TAG, barcode)
                                listener(barcode)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    imageProxy.close()
                }
        }
```

Now the scanning of the barcode is lightning fast!

Answer (score 1):

Use image process like this.

```
scanner.process(InputImage.fromBitmap(image.toBitmap(), image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees))
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                    if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                        barcodes.firstOrNull()?.rawValue?.let { barcode ->
                            Log.d(TAG, barcode)
                                listener(barcode)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    imageProxy.close()
                }
        }
```

and close image proxy after proceed the image like below code.

```
imageProxy.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Whatever @Bruce Wayne suggest works !!!

```
.addOnCompleteListener {
    imageProxy.close()
 }
```

Comment: You should delete the answer and upvote + accept Bruce's answer instead